# joining character matrices with delimiter python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, character, delimiter

I am trying to create a large dimensional numpy character array (5+ dimensions) where each bin represents a combination of numbers. These numbers I'll deliminate (probably with /) so I can string split the information later when needed. So in interest of TIME SAVING specially when this gets to be like a 20+ dimensional array. I was hoping to do this with matrixs instead of having 20 loops going. Please find below a two dimensional example with loops and any ideas how I can do this with out the loops will be helpful.

```
import numpy as np
storing_array = np.chararray( [80, 98], itemsize = 100 )
for x1 in range(0, 80):
  for x2 in range(0, 98):
    storing_array[x1, x2] = '/'.join([str(x1), str(x2)])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Flatten the arrays, do `tolist` and do this joining with python lists and strings,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conveniently define your `x1` and `x2` with `np.arange`, convert them to `str` and then convert them to `object` so they have support for certain operations:

```
x2=np.arange(98).astype(str).astype(object)
x1=np.arange(80).astype(str).astype(object)
```

Now add `/` to `x1` in place:

```
x1+='/'
```

And now get all the combinations using np.broadcasting:

```
result=x1[:,None]+x2
```

Comment: Thanks! it was easy to extend this method to five variables

Comment: Nice switch to `object` dtype.  Gives access to some string operations that `np.char` doesn't provide.

Comment: @hpaulj I find the docs on object arrays a bit lacking, but there is some basic info [here](https://gist.github.com/ahaldane/c3f9bcf1f62d898be7c7#file-objectarrays-mkd). I found that *some* operations on large enough object arrays (len>1E3) can be 2-3 times faster than equivalent list comprehensions

Comment: It's hard to tell in the `gist` document was is actual and what is proposed.  For example `np.pytype` may be in the future.  It is still hard to control the depth of nested arrays/lists.